I have 108 flags left today
According to the help center:

...This number may increase to up to 100 flags per day

But:


There was a rather large spam wave so the powers that be temporarily(?) increased the number of available flags.

Update:Acording to Dragonrage in a chat message (backed up by Laurel in a comment below and this rollback by Spevacus):

The base number of flags everyone can cast has been returned to the previous default values. In the case of another spam wave, this can be temporarily changed again while SE investigates potential changes to help deal with these sorts of scenarios.

My flags have gone back to normal and I'm guessing everyone else's have as well. The old answer is preserved below.

I had 326 earlier. According to Spevacus in a chat message:

SE has temporarily upped the base number of flags everyone can cast network-wide to 100, as a response to the network-wide spam wave we're receiving. If you have the flag posts privilege, you should have 100 available to cast by default now. In addition, the maximum number of flags you can have as a result of helpful flag count + reputation is now 1000, up from 100.


Tagging in real quick to say: Technically, my use of "temporarily" may/may not be accurate here. While I have no reason to believe this will be permanent, I also have not received notice of when these settings will be reverted to their prior values. This change simply is at the moment.

@Spevacus Have you recieved notice that it will eventually return to their normal values or not? Because quite a few temporary changes are still in effect, ex 4 flag spam nuking.

How many people were ever running out of flags before? I think addressing the problem is a matter of getting more people to look out for spam.

@KarlKnechtel At the height, I counted 65 pages of (not deleted) spam questions, or about 1000 total, (not including spam answers and comments) on Webapps, which was the site most heavily targeted. It's a small site, so everyone was running out of flags (you get 10 flags at the start, and it's 4 to delete one post). There's nothing special about that site, any could have been targeted, so I guess that's why the limit was increased across the board.

For the good of the order, the formula for determining the extra flags you get from reputation and helpful flags is (with these adjustments in place): 100 + ((helpful flag count - declined flag count) / 10) + (reputation / 2000) | Max: 1000

Apparently the modified limit is gone?

@nalka Spam has gone back to normal levels, so they removed the extra flags, which were a temporary solution (and could easily be overused). There's going to be discussions on what a more appropriate solution would be going forward. Maybe we'll see a permanent solution given to flaggers eventually in addition to the work they've done behind the scenes.
